# Mongodb problems with sorting in $lookup

Tags: mongodb

This is the query I'm currently working on:

```
db.lenses.aggregate([
                    {
                        $lookup: {
                            from: 'treatments',
                            localField: 'treatments.type',
                            foreignField: '_id',
                            as: 'treatments'
                        }
                    },
                    { $unwind: '$treatments' },
                    { $match: { 'treatments.priceList.validityYear': 2019 } },
                    { $sort: { 'treatments.priceList.validityStart': 1 } },
                ]).pretty();
```

but the last $sort in aggregate is currently ignored.

The outcome I want to achieve is to match and sort the lookup collection, not the lenses collection.

validityStart is a ISODATE

I'm using Mongodb in Altas.

I'm tryng to use the lookup pipeline, but it seems to join all the treatments, not just the referred ones.

**EDIT**

here's the schema for the lenses collection

```
lens: Schema = 
    name: { type: String },
    treatments: [
         type: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'treatment', required: true },
         colors: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'color' }]
    ]
```

and here's the schema for the treatment collection, referred by treatments.type on the lens schema.

```
treatments: Schema = 
    name: { type: String },
    priceList: [
            {
                buyingPrice: { type: Number, required: true },
                sellingPrice: { type: Number, required: true },
                validityYear: { type: Number, required: true },
                validityStart: { type: Date, required: true },
                validityEnd: { type: Date, required: true }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Can you show me your schema? Is there any array field in treatments?

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti I edited the question to include the schemas